# Spark submit to remote yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two clodera hadoop cluster (prod and dev) and one client machine. This client machine is configured to be a gateway node to the prod cluster.
From this I am able to submit a spark job to my prod cluster using

```
spark-submit --master yarn job_script.py
```

Now I would like to submit the same job to my dev cluster from this client machine.
I tried using

```
spark-submit --master yarn://<dev_resource_manager_ip>:8032 job_script.py
```

But this doesn't seem to work and my job is still getting submitted to prod cluster. How could I tell `spark-submit` to submit job to dev cluster resource manager instead of prod cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Create directory with all Hadoop XMLs for dev cluster and override `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable before `spark-submit`.

Comment: This is rather cumbersome. Is there any other simple way to do this using command-line arguments or job conf?

Comment: Probably not. Spark uses hadoop yarn client libraries to submit the application and this standard library reads configuration xml files in particular directory.